# Access mapped scalars in ParaView Python (actual colors)

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

How can I get the colors which are produced by mapping scalars through a color transfer function in ParaView Python Shell? I am aware of the following:

```
dp = GetDisplayProperties()
lut = dp.LookupTable
```

But this returns a `PVLookupTable` which does not have `MapScalarsThroughTable()` from e.g. `vtkScalarsToColors`.

I need the actual colors for some custom exporter functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
lut = GetColorTransferFunction('ArrayName')
lut.RGBPoints
```

You will need to do the interpolation yourself from this. There are no methods to access that in Python.